# Background color is incorrect on first page for some reason

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

File example: [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LXOuGmk67hQRwLXi5GBx-5n3-CJ_NV7h)
Issue: I'm trying to decide if text is visible on page. To achieve that, for each *Fill* command I save its path + color, something like that:

```
    public class FillNonZeroRule extends OperatorProcessor {
        @Override
        public final void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
            PDGraphicsState gs = getGraphicsState();    
            linePath.setWindingRule(GeneralPath.WIND_NON_ZERO);
            addFillPath(gs.getNonStrokingColor());
            linePath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "f";
        }
    }

    void addFillPath(PDColor color) {
        filledPaths.put((GeneralPath)linePath.clone(), color);
    }
```

And, this is how I later get background for each character:

```
private PDColor getCharacterBackgroundColor(TextPosition text) {
        PDColor color = null;           
        for (Map.Entry<GeneralPath, PDColor> filledPath : filledPaths.entrySet()) {
            Vector center = getTextPositionCenterPoint(text);
            if (filledPath.getKey().contains(lowerLeftX + center.getX(), lowerLeftY + center.getY())) {
                color = filledPath.getValue();                  
            }
        }

        return color;
    }
```

Also, save colors for each text position as well.
Then I try to identify if that background color is same as character color.
And what is interesting, for first page background color and text colors for headers (lines in the top with background) are both 2301728 (int RGB value) - which is incorrect, however, for page two, text color is 2301728 and background color is 14145754 (correct!).
So my question is what is causing incorrect background on first page...
Thanks in advance!

Entire class is below:

```
public class PdfToTextInfoConverter extends PDFTextStripper {

    private int rotation = 0;

    private float lowerLeftX = 0;

    private float lowerLeftY = 0;

    private PDPage page = null;

    private GeneralPath linePath;

    private Map<GeneralPath, PDColor> filledPaths;

    private Map<TextPosition, PDColor> nonStrokingColors;

    public PdfToTextInfoConverter(PDDocument pddfDoc) throws IOException {
        addOperator(new SetStrokingColorSpace());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColorSpace());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColorN());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColor());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingDeviceGrayColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceGrayColor());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingDeviceRGBColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceRGBColor());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingDeviceCMYKColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceCMYKColor());

        addOperator(new AppendRectangleToPath());
        addOperator(new ClipEvenOddRule());
        addOperator(new ClipNonZeroRule());
        addOperator(new ClosePath());
        addOperator(new CurveTo());
        addOperator(new CurveToReplicateFinalPoint());
        addOperator(new CurveToReplicateInitialPoint());
        addOperator(new EndPath());
        addOperator(new FillEvenOddAndStrokePath());
        addOperator(new FillEvenOddRule());
        addOperator(new FillNonZeroAndStrokePath());
        addOperator(new FillNonZeroRule());
        addOperator(new LineTo());
        addOperator(new MoveTo());
        addOperator(new StrokePath());
        document = pddfDoc;
    }

    public void stripPage(int pageNum, int resolution) throws IOException {
        this.setStartPage(pageNum + 1);
        this.setEndPage(pageNum + 1);
        page = document.getPage(pageNum);
        rotation = page.getRotation();
        linePath = new GeneralPath();
        filledPaths = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        nonStrokingColors = new HashMap<>();    
        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        writeText(document, dummy); // This call starts the parsing process and calls writeString repeatedly.
    }

    @Override
    public void processPage(PDPage page) throws IOException {
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.getCropBox();

        lowerLeftX = pageSize.getLowerLeftX();
        lowerLeftY = pageSize.getLowerLeftY();

        super.processPage(page);
    }

    private Integer getCharacterBackgroundColor(TextPosition text) {
        Integer fillColorRgb = null;
        try {           
            for (Map.Entry<GeneralPath, PDColor> filledPath : filledPaths.entrySet()) {
                Vector center = getTextPositionCenterPoint(text);
                if (filledPath.getKey().contains(lowerLeftX + center.getX(), lowerLeftY + center.getY())) {
                    fillColorRgb = filledPath.getValue().toRGB();                   
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Could not convert color to RGB", e);
        }
        return fillColorRgb;
    }

    private int getCharacterColor(TextPosition text) {
        int colorRgb = 0; // assume it's black even if we could not convert to RGB
        try {
            colorRgb = nonStrokingColors.get(text).toRGB();         
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Could not convert color to RGB", e);
        }
        return colorRgb;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
        PDGraphicsState gs = getGraphicsState();
        // check opacity for stroke and fill text 
        if (gs.getAlphaConstant() < Constants.EPSILON && gs.getNonStrokeAlphaConstant() < Constants.EPSILON) {
            return;
        }                       

        Vector center = getTextPositionCenterPoint(text);
        Area area = gs.getCurrentClippingPath();
        if (area == null || area.contains(lowerLeftX + center.getX(), lowerLeftY + center.getY())) {            
            nonStrokingColors.put(text, gs.getNonStrokingColor());
            super.processTextPosition(text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {           
            Integer characterColor = getCharacterColor(text);
            Integer characterBackgroundColor = getCharacterBackgroundColor(text);
        }
    }

    private Vector getTextPositionCenterPoint(TextPosition text) {
        Matrix textMatrix = text.getTextMatrix();
        Vector start = textMatrix.transform(new Vector(0, 0));
        Vector center = null;
        switch (rotation) {
        case 0:
            center = new Vector(start.getX() + text.getWidth()/2, start.getY()); 
            break;
        case 90:
            center = new Vector(start.getX(), start.getY() + text.getWidth()/2);
            break;
        case 180:
            center = new Vector(start.getX() - text.getWidth()/2, start.getY());
            break;
        case 270:
            center = new Vector(start.getX(), start.getY() - text.getWidth()/2);
            break;
        default:
            center = new Vector(start.getX() + text.getWidth()/2, start.getY());
            break;
        }

        return center;
    }

    void addFillPath(PDColor color) {
        filledPaths.put((GeneralPath)linePath.clone(), color);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing special about the contents of the PDF in question; thus, this most likely is an issue in your code. Unfortunately there is too little code to reproduce anything. My guesses would be that either **A** your `getTextPositionCenterPoint` is a bit off (probably ignoring transformation matrices) and by chance returns a location in the dark line (which is drawn as a filled rectangle using the dark foreground color) instead of the light box or **B** your using a `Map` to store pairs of path and color somehow backfired. But these are really shots in the dark...

Comment: If you cannot share enough code to allow reproduction of the error, please add the full contents of `filledPaths` and `text` objects for a situation with an incorrect result is determined, and please indicate which letter on which page is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! updated question with code

Comment: Missing: `getTextPositionCenterPoint` refers to a `rotation` variable that's not there. (`Constants.EPSILON` and `logger` are also missing but I think I can replace them properly.)

Comment: Sorry, added rotation definition. logger you can just remove, and epsilon is just 
public static final double EPSILON = 0.000000000000001;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in PDFBox.

(Well, there also is an issue in your code but the reason for the problem at hand is PDFBox based.)

#### The bug

The problem is that the `PDColor.toRGB()` call in

```java
fillColorRgb = filledPath.getValue().toRGB();
```

damages the color value itself for the specific color in question!

The color space in question is a separation color space. Thus, `PDColor.toRGB()` calls `PDSeparation.toRGB(float[])` using its `components` member as parameter.

If the RGB value for the given parameter is not yet in the cached in the color space, `PDSeparation.toRGB(float[])` evaluates the `tintTransform` for the given parameters. For the color space in question the tint transform is a `PDFunctionType0` instance. Thus, `PDFunctionType0.eval(float[])` is called.

Unfortunately `PDFunctionType0.eval(float[])` assumes it can use the array parameter `input` for its own purposes:

```
input[i] = clipToRange(input[i], domain.getMin(), domain.getMax());
input[i] = interpolate(input[i], domain.getMin(), domain.getMax(), 
        encodeValues.getMin(), encodeValues.getMax());
input[i] = clipToRange(input[i], 0, sizeValues[i] - 1);
```

But this array is the original `PDColor` member `components`. So this evaluation changes the single component of your color object from 0.172 to 43.688.

Later `toRGB` calls for that color find the 43.688 (or other value due to further unwanted changes) which is far beyond the maximum value 1.0, so they clip it down to 1.0 and transform from there. But the color in that color space with component 1.0 is exactly the color used for the foreground text. Thus, your code thinks background and foreground are the same.

#### A work-around

To fix this issue the method `PDFunctionType0.eval(float[])` should be rewritten not to write into its parameter array. A quick way to do so is to add

```
input = input.clone();
```

at the top of that method `PDFunctionType0.eval(float[])`.

#### An issue in your code

Your method `getTextPositionCenterPoint` uses the page rotation to determine the center of the base line of the given `TextPosition`. This only is correct, though, for text that after the page rotation is drawn upright. In case of your document, though, this is not the case. So instead of the page rotation you need to analyze the text matrix for the actual direction of the text.

This won't make much of a difference in your case, though, because the `TextPosition.getWidth()` value you use as character widths also is calculated based on the page rotation. As the page in question is not rotated but the text direction is rotated by 90°, `TextPosition.getWidth()` always returns 0... You might want to work with `getWidthDirAdj()` instead...

Comment: Thanks @mkl! Fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4461 , snapshot at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.14-SNAPSHOT/